# Node.js: set Multer destination based on FormData values

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest, multer

I'm creating an `XMLHttpRequest` (`xhr`) that sends a `FormData` object that contains a file and some values to the `Node.js`(`Express`) server. I'm using `Multer`, as I can't use `bodyParser` with `multipart` data.

```
router.post("/submit", function(req, res) {
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        // set destination here
    })

    var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).any();

    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        // I can access req.body here
    });
});
```

The `destination` that I set in `storage` will depend on the values of the `body` object (like `req.body.product`). But I'm not able to access `req.body` before calling `multer()`. How can I access `req.body` before setting `multer.storage`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the `destination` config property for `diskStorage()` [as shown in the `multer` documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#diskstorage). For example:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    var newAbsoluteDir = /* calculate based on `req.body` here */;
    cb(null, newAbsoluteDir);
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage });

// ...

router.post('/submit', upload.any(), function(req, res) {
  // ...
});
```

As the documentation notes, any non-file fields you need to access inside those `multer` callbacks need to be positioned before the file field you're processing because multipart/form-data requests have their fields ordered. So if you have a static HTML form, it's the literal position of the input, select, etc. elements that matters. For XHR, it's the order in which you call `formData.append()` for each field.

Comment: Thank you :') Like you mention in the answer, I had to change the order in which I call `formData.append()` to put the text values before the files.

Comment: raul your comments saved me. @mscdex please update this in your answer

Comment: @mscdex I mean the comment  by raul, ", I had to change the order in which I call", this is important else I am not able to access fields sent through api request, file field should be the last in dict, atleast in POSTMAN, where I tested

Comment: Thanks @Raul
Only the upload.any() doesn't matter. This even works with the `upload.single('<fieldName>')` or `upload.fileds([{name: '<fieldName>'}])`. 

The actual cause is, the fields that are appended **before** the file attachment will only be accessible.